# The revelation of Quranic verses

Tags: quran, sunni, shiism, shia-sunni

Shiites believe that the reason for the revelation of many verses of the Holy Quran is the Commander of the Faithful Ali ibn Abi Talib (many verses of the Holy Quran are about him)

For example, verse 55 of Surah Ma'idah:

إِنَّمَا وَلِيُّكُمُ اللَّهُ وَرَسُولُهُ وَالَّذِينَ آمَنُوا الَّذِينَ يُقِيمُونَ الصَّلَاةَ وَيُؤْتُونَ الزَّكَاةَ وَهُمْ رَاكِعُونَ

Your guardian is only God and His Messenger, and those who believe: those who perform the prayer and pay the alms while bowing.

Other examples: verse 207 of Surah Baqara, verses 3 and 67 of Surah Ma'idah, verse 7 of Surah Bina, verse 4 of Surah Tahrir, verse 61 of Surah Al-Imran. , Verse 23 of Surah Shura and ........
Do the Sunnis agree with the Shiites that there are many verses in the Qur'an about Ali ibn Abi Talib?

Comment: As is written this is a vague question, first of all what do you mean by "'Ali ibn abi Talib is the revelation of many verses"? I guess there's a missing word saying something like "is referred to in many verses". Nevertheless without pointing at the content which was identified as pointing or referring to him you'll leave us guessing...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to ask my questions more clearly, Thank's